# Does decimal math use the FPU

Tags: decimal, fpu

Does decimal math use the FPU?

I would think that the answer is yes, but I'm not sure, since a decimal is not a floating point, but a fixed precision number.

I'm looking mostly for .NET, but a general answer would be useful too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regards to .NET and more specifically C#, no, `System.Decimal` does not use the FPU because the type is emulated in software.

Also, `System.Decimal` **is** a floating point number, not a fixed precision number like commonly found in a database. The type is actually a *decimal floating point* that uses 10 for its base as opposed to a *binary floating point* (i.e. `System.Single` or `System.Double`) which uses 2 as its base. It still has the same precision problems if you attempt to store a fraction that cannot be exactly represented, for example, 1/3.

Comment: I wonder why `Decimal` uses floating point?  A 128-bit fixed point type could guarantee that a+b-a will in all cases either yield b or throw an exception, but for `Decimal` that equality doesn't hold.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, modern languages in general support *floating point math* and *integer math*, and that's it; there's no direct support for fixed point, BCD, etc. Floating-point math is going to be done using floating-point processor instructions; modern architectures don't include a separate FPU.